# minidlna is running as root. is this bad?

Tags: root, privileges

I installed minidlna from the tarball. The version using apt-get install minidlna is a little older and does not have compatibility features i need. I auto start minidlna by executing sudo update-rc.d minidlna defaults. However, I notice it runs as root. Is this bad? How do i get it to run as my user instead of as root.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MiniDLNA) has instructions on running minidlna as a non-root user

Comment: thanks - i noticed that page. I guess it is better to run as non-root. I will do it.

Answer (score 1):

**Long story short**: Yes, it is advisable to run processes under non-root user privileges whenever possible.

It is not the only reason, but running non-root user services can help limit the damage caused by bugs or attacks. However, `minidlna` is almost like a one-way communication process. This means that if I were a hacker, I wouldn't use the DLNA protocol to hack a system. So yes, it is better to run processes under non-root. But for `minidlna`, it may not be necessary.

---

Following is my setting for `minidlna`.
(change `dummy` to your username)

#### Create config file on the user home and make changes

```sh
mkdir -p ~/.config/minidlna
cp /etc/minidlna.conf ~/.config/minidlna/
vi ~/.config/minidlna/minidlna.conf
```

Add/uncomment following lines

```
db_dir=/home/dummy/.config/minidlna/db
log_dir=/var/log
```

#### Edit minidlna systemd file

```
sudo vi /etc/default/minidlna
```

Add/uncomment following lines

```
CONFIGFILE=/home/dummy/.config/minidlna/minidlna.conf
LOGFILE=/var/log/minidlna.log
USER=dummy
GROUP=dummy
```

#### Restart minidlna service

```
sudo systemctl start minidlna
```

#### Check status

```
systemctl status minidlna
```